# How to define own JNDI name for EJB in an ear

Tags: java, jboss, jndi, ejb-3.1, ear

I have an `ear` which has  `ejb.jar`, `core.jar`.

`core.jar` use `lookup` to find the bean at run time. Now the `jndi` path is `mysystem-server-component-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/MyServiceBean/local`  which means `<earname>/<beanname>/<localinterface>`

I want to define `JNDI` like  `MyServiceBean/local`. Where my MyServiceBean is the ejb bean and it use local interface.

I use `EJB 3.1` without `ejb-jar.xml` and `jboss.xml`. All the wiring done through `annotation`.

How can I define my own `JNDI` name which I can lookup

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe when I researched EJB 3.1 (on JBoss, but shouldn't matter) that the you could no longer specify the JNDI name like you could in previous versions.  I think the 3.1 spec locked down the naming standard, like you mentioned, <ear>/<beanname>/<interface name>.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `@EJB(mappedName = "yourJndiName")`?

If your JNDI lookups are not working as expected, then you should always check your JNDI tree from within the administration frontend (should be somewhere in jmx-console/JBoss/service=JNDIView or similar). Sometimes the name of the remote interface, etc. is added to your JNDI name by your application server.

Comment: yes I tried that did not work for me. I use jboss AS6. MY JNDI tree starts from ear name and then ejb jar name and then the bean. I used this [link](https://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#Are_Global_JNDI_names_portable_How_do) didn't work either. Not sure is this because of JBoss 6